# determine period of the limit cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

The question I was working on said: determine the equation of the limit cycle to:

$x'' + (4x^2 + x'^2 -4x)x' + 4x = 0 $

What is it's period.

I have found the limit cycle:

$x^2 +4y^2 =4$

Where $y=x'$

I'd like to be directed to some examples that I can work through so that I can start.
It's been many years since I've looked at problems like this and I fear my brain has turned to mush. :(

Comment: You know that the solution is $x(t)=2\sin(t/2+\phi)$? There is no limit cycle, the solution is periodic from the start. Or is there some bigger problem around this?

Comment: @LutzL I have edited my post to include the entire question.  I can't remember how to find the solution you have given for $x(t)$.  What online sources can I go to so that I can re-learn all this awesome calculus that I have forgotten? :(

Comment: Are you sure about the $-4x$ in the middle term? And should the limit cycle equation not be $x'^2+4x^2=4$, which implies $x''+4x=0$?

Comment: @LutzL can you suggest textbooks or online sites I can go to so that I can relearn all this?  I really need to get back to the bare bones and work up.

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an error in the equation, in the middle term it should not be "$-4x$" but "$-4$" to get an easily solvable tutorial problem. The phase portrait for both variants confirms this difference in difficulty.

[image]

Going by the corrected second case, the limit cycle coincides with the root of the middle factor. Using $V(t)=\frac12(x'(t)^2+4x(t)^2-4)$ one gets the differential equation
$$
V'=-2V\cdot x'^2
$$
so that the curve $V=0$ is a stable equilibrium.

This means that the equation of the limit cycle is $4x^2+y^2=4$, writing it as a circle equation $(2x)^2+y^2=2^2$ one gets for the initial point $x(0)=\sinϕ$, $x'(0)=y(0)=2\cosϕ$.

Then differentiate through to get
$$
2x'(x''+4x)=0
$$
which either gives a constant solution $x=\pm1$, $x'=0$ or the harmonic oscillator with angular velocity $\omega=2$.

Combined with the initial conditions the solution is
$$
x(t)=\sin(2t+ϕ)
$$
giving $\pi$ as period.